# Using zmq_poll and zmq_send() on a same socket

Tags: zeromq

I'm confused by a warning in the [api of zmq_poll](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-poll): "The zmq_send() function will clear all pending events on a socket. Thus, if you use zmq_poll() to monitor input on a socket, use it before output as well, and process all events after each zmq_poll() call."

I don't understand what that means. Since events are *level-triggered*. If I call `zmq_send()` and then `zmq_poll()`, any pending messages in the socket's buffer should trigger the `zmq_poll` again immediately. Why one needs to "use it (`zmq_poll`) before output as well" or "process all events after each zmq_poll() call"?

Comment: I'm sort of with you, but can you clarify exactly what you're asking? Not sure what you mean by _Why one needs to "use it (zmq_poll) before output as well" or "process all events after each zmq_poll() call"?_

Comment: @raffian I'm using `zmq_poll` to monitor the input on two sockets. And I'm also sending out messages via one of those two sockets. Is it safe if I do `zmq_send()` before I handle all the input messages on that socket? I don't want to lose any messages.

Comment: @raffian The sentences in double quotes are copied from the API document that I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your point, the documentation is confusing. Here's a simple test in Java using a client-side `DEALER` socket with a poller (from [asyncsrv](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java%3aasyncsrv)) . The server sends 3 messages to the client. The client polls and outputs each message it receives. I've added `send()` in the client to test your theory. Assuming `send()` clears the poller, we expect the client to output receipt of only a single message:

**Server**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    ZMQ.Socket server = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
    server.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    server.sendMore("clientId");
    server.send("msg1");

    server.sendMore("clientId");
    server.send("msg2");

    server.sendMore("clientId");
    server.send("msg3");
}
```

**Client**

```
public void run() {
    socket = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER);
    socket.setIdentity("clientId".getBytes());
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

    ZMQ.Poller poller = new ZMQ.Poller(1);
    poller.register(socket, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);

    while (true) {
        poller.poll();
        if (poller.pollin(0)) {
            String msg = socket.recvStr(0);
            System.out.println("Client got msg: " + msg);
            socket.send("whatever", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

outputs...

```
Client got msg: msg1
Client got msg: msg2
Client got msg: msg3
```

Based on the results, doing `send()` does not clear the poller for `socket`, and it should be obvious why. We configured the poller with `POLLIN`, meaning the poller listens for *inbound* messages to `socket`. When doing `socket.send()`, it creates *outbound* messages, on which the poller is not listening.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I'm using C++. But I believe bindings should make not difference here